# Make android keyboard stick on the top of input by using adjust pan

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, keyboard, offset

i am new for jquery mobile. I am using adjust pan when onkeyboardshow. I follow this solution which posted by **kieranroneill**

*[Phonegap Android Application not adjusting pan on keyboardshow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18599519/phonegap-android-application-not-adjusting-pan-on-keyboardshow)*

```
   package com.com.app;

import org.apache.cordova.Config;
import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class BDH extends DroidGap
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml

        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_MASK_ADJUST);

        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
        //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html")

        final View activityRootView = ((ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content)).getChildAt(0);

        activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() 
            {
                // r will be populated with the coordinates of your view that area still visible.
                Rect r = new Rect();

                activityRootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);

                int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - (r.bottom - r.top);

                // If more than 100 pixels, its probably a keyboard...
                if (heightDiff > 100) 
                {
                                    // Fire off a function to the JavaScript.
                    this.sendJavascript("try { onKeyboardShowing(); } catch (e) {};");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

But now is my question is it possible make the scroll to **stick on the top of keyboard** instead of set it to static value .Thanks

```
$('body').scrollTo(fieldFocused, 500, {offset:-??});
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.smartrealtor"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <supports-screens
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:resizeable="true"
    android:anyDensity="true"
    />



    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_DOCUMENTS"/>

 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"


         >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.smartrealtor.MainActivity"
            android:label="SmartRealtor" 
             android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboard|screenLayout"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" 
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
          >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity 
            android:name="org.apache.cordova.DroidGap" 
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
             android:alwaysRetainTaskState ="true"

            > 
            <intent-filter></intent-filter> 
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
 Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 distributed with this work for additional information
 regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

 http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

 Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 specific language governing permissions and limitations
 under the License.
-->
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        id        = "io.cordova.helloCordova"
        version   = "2.0.0">
    <name>Hello Cordova</name>

    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>

    <author href="http://cordova.io" email="dev@cordova.apache.org">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>

    <access origin="*"/>
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
      <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
      <preference name="KeyboardShrinksView" value="false" />



    <content src="index.html" />

    <preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
    <!--
      <preference name="splashscreen" value="resourceName" />
      <preference name="backgroundColor" value="0xFFF" />
      <preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="20000" />
      <preference name="InAppBrowserStorageEnabled" value="true" />
      <preference name="disallowOverscroll" value="true" />
      <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false" />
      <preference name="KeyboardShrinksView" value="true" />
    -->

    <feature name="App">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Geolocation">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Device">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Device"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Accelerometer">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.AccelListener"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Compass">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.CompassListener"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Media">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.AudioHandler"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Camera">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Contacts">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.ContactManager"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="File">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.FileUtils"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="NetworkStatus">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Notification">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Storage">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Storage"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="FileTransfer">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Capture">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Capture"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Battery">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.BatteryListener"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="SplashScreen">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Echo">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Echo"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Globalization">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.Globalization"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="InAppBrowser">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser"/>
    </feature>
    <feature name="Calendar">
  <param name="android-package" value="nl.xservices.plugins.Calendar" />
</feature>
<feature name="SocialSharing">
  <param name="android-package" value="nl.xservices.plugins.SocialSharing" />
</feature>

    <!-- Deprecated plugins element. Remove in 3.0 -->
<plugins>
    <plugin name="App" value="org.apache.cordova.App"/>
    <plugin name="Geolocation" value="org.apache.cordova.GeoBroker"/>
    <plugin name="Device" value="org.apache.cordova.Device"/>
    <plugin name="Accelerometer" value="org.apache.cordova.AccelListener"/>
    <plugin name="Compass" value="org.apache.cordova.CompassListener"/>
    <plugin name="Media" value="org.apache.cordova.AudioHandler"/>
    <plugin name="Camera" value="org.apache.cordova.CameraLauncher"/>
    <plugin name="Contacts" value="org.apache.cordova.ContactManager"/>
    <plugin name="File" value="org.apache.cordova.FileUtils"/>
    <plugin name="NetworkStatus" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager"/>
    <plugin name="Notification" value="org.apache.cordova.Notification"/>
    <plugin name="Storage" value="org.apache.cordova.Storage"/>
    <plugin name="Temperature" value="org.apache.cordova.TempListener"/>
    <plugin name="FileTransfer" value="org.apache.cordova.FileTransfer"/>
    <plugin name="Capture" value="org.apache.cordova.Capture"/>
    <plugin name="Battery" value="org.apache.cordova.BatteryListener"/>
    <plugin name="SplashScreen" value="org.apache.cordova.SplashScreen"/>
    <plugin name="Echo" value="org.apache.cordova.Echo" />
    <plugin name="BarcodeScanner" value="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.BarcodeScanner"/>
    <plugin name="PushPlugin" value="com.plugin.gcm.PushPlugin" />
    <plugin name="Calendar" value="nl.xservices.plugins.Calendar"/>
   <plugin name="SocialSharing" value="nl.xservices.plugins.SocialSharing"/>

</plugins>
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
i hope your phonegap version is updated 3.0 >
In res->xml->config.xml

Replace

`<preference name="fullscreen" value="true" />`

To

```
 <preference name="fullscreen" value="false" />
```

and  in BDH.java file remove your personal added native code.

Comment: Hi my current version is using 2.9 . btw i also change the fullscreen to false. But adjust pan is not working if i remove those native code

Comment: if possible please update your phpnegap latest and can you please show me your AndroidMainfest.xml

Comment: Hi i update  the xml. Btw i am not possible to update to 3.0 cos i got lot plugin is using 2.9

Comment: which plugin you are use

Comment: sharesocial, resize image and etc it causing me lot of time if change to 3.0 . Btw please c my latest update. thanks

Comment: Try  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"   to adjustResize